# Joining all meshes in any context gets error

Tags: python, mesh

When I run this code:

```
import bpy

# Select all and only meshes.
item = 'MESH'
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type=item)

# List of all known subcontexts.
subcontexts_list = ['INVOKE_DEFAULT', 'INVOKE_REGION_WIN', 'INVOKE_REGION_CHANNELS',
                    'INVOKE_REGION_PREVIEW', 'INVOKE_AREA', 'INVOKE_SCREEN',
                    'EXEC_DEFAULT', 'EXEC_REGION_WIN', 'EXEC_REGION_CHANNELS',
                    'EXEC_REGION_PREVIEW', 'EXEC_AREA', 'EXEC_SCREEN']

# Try to join using each subcontext.
for sub_context in subcontexts_list:
    try:
        bpy.ops.object.join(sub_context)

    except Exception as e:
        print('{}: {}'.format(sub_context, e))
```

I get these errors:

```
INVOKE_DEFAULT: Operator bpy.ops.object.join.poll() failed, context is incorrect
INVOKE_REGION_WIN: Operator bpy.ops.object.join.poll() failed, context is incorrect
INVOKE_REGION_CHANNELS: Operator bpy.ops.object.join.poll() failed, context is incorrect
INVOKE_REGION_PREVIEW: Operator bpy.ops.object.join.poll() failed, context is incorrect
INVOKE_AREA: Operator bpy.ops.object.join.poll() failed, context is incorrect
INVOKE_SCREEN: Operator bpy.ops.object.join.poll() failed, context is incorrect
EXEC_DEFAULT: Operator bpy.ops.object.join.poll() failed, context is incorrect
EXEC_REGION_WIN: Operator bpy.ops.object.join.poll() failed, context is incorrect
EXEC_REGION_CHANNELS: Operator bpy.ops.object.join.poll() failed, context is incorrect
EXEC_REGION_PREVIEW: Operator bpy.ops.object.join.poll() failed, context is incorrect
EXEC_AREA: Operator bpy.ops.object.join.poll() failed, context is incorrect
EXEC_SCREEN: Operator bpy.ops.object.join.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure one of your mesh objects is active. You will get that error if you try to join without one being active.

This works with 2.80

```
import bpy

#Deselect all
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

#Mesh objects
MSH_OBJS = [m for m in bpy.context.scene.objects if m.type == 'MESH']

for OBJS in MSH_OBJS:
    #Select all mesh objects
    OBJS.select_set(state=True)

    #Makes one active
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = OBJS

#Joins objects
bpy.ops.object.join()
```